# Procedure to determine minimum number of stamps to make up a given monetary value

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

I'm following the Udacity intro to CompSci, and I don't know why my answer isn't quite correct:

**Question:**

> Define a procedure, stamps, which takes as its input a positive
>   integer in pence and returns the number of 5p, 2p and 1p stamps (p is
>   pence) required to make up that value. The return value should be a
>   tuple of three numbers (that is, your return statement should be
>   followed by the number of 5p, the number of 2p, and the nuber of 1p
>   stamps).
>
> Your answer should use as few total stamps as possible by first using
>   as many 5p stamps as possible, then 2 pence stamps and finally 1p
>   stamps as needed to make up the total.

**My attempt**

```
def stamps(targetvalue):
    currentvalue = 0
    fives = 0
    twos = 0
    ones = 0
    while True:
        if targetvalue == currentvalue:
            return fives, twos, ones
        if targetvalue - currentvalue >= 5:
            fives = fives + 1
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 5
        if targetvalue - currentvalue < 5:
            if targetvalue - currentvalue >= 2:
                twos = twos + 1
                currentvalue = currentvalue + 2
            if targetvalue - currentvalue == 1:
                ones = ones + 1
                currentvalue = currentvalue + 1
            else:
                return fives, twos, ones
```

Comment: Maybe the modulo operator can help with the `while True`?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury thanks for responding! I haven't learnt the modulo operator, so I think it should be possible without (otherwise it wouldn't be a question on the course)

Comment: My answer will feature the modulo (or remainder) operator, and it helps a lot with this stuff, so i suggest you learn about it.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury thank you! I certainly appreciate your help (by all means please show me how you would solve), but I will also see if someone can help me with the code as I tried to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not returning the correct answer due to its breaking out of the loop early:

```
        if targetvalue - currentvalue == 1:
            ones = ones + 1
            currentvalue = currentvalue + 1
        else:
            return fives, twos, ones
```

The `if` statement can be reached when `targetvalue - currentvalue` is equal to 2. Because it is not equal to 1, the `return` statement is executed even though `currentvalue` is less than `targetvalue`.  Removing the `else` condition should give the correct values.

That said, an implementation that adheres to the final sentence of the problem description might be clearer. First doing 5p, then 2p, and finally 1p. Here's how the original code can be reworked to do that:

```
def stamps(targetvalue):
    currentvalue = 0
    fives = 0
    twos = 0
    ones = 0

    while targetvalue - currentvalue >= 5:
        fives = fives + 1
        currentvalue = currentvalue + 5

    while targetvalue - currentvalue >= 2:
        twos = twos + 1
        currentvalue = currentvalue + 2

    while targetvalue - currentvalue >= 1:
        ones = ones + 1
        currentvalue = currentvalue + 1

    return fives, twos, ones
```

Limiting the loops to a few lines and using the same pattern for all values makes the code easier to follow and less error prone.

Comment: Hi, this answer was really helpful as it was helping me using the tools I was trying to use. The other answers, while it is good for me to learn new tools, ignored the method I was trying to follow. Will review a bit later but it looks really clear to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Let me start by saying that a `while True:` loop with a `return` embedded is a bad idea. It works, yes, but the train of logic becomes more complicated to follow the more branches are within the loop. Now if you had, say, 10p, 20p & 50p coins, this would become more and more complicated until it reached a point where you would want to rewrite it in a more sensible way.

With that out of the way, let's get on with the review.

1. Hard-code as little as possible. Try to use more parameters. All those 5's are for a specific use-case. Try accepting them as parameters in your function.
2. Return a `dict` instead of a `tuple` - it associates each price with a count of stamps of that price and makes the returned value more general with respect to prices.
3. `while True:` is a bad idea, as explained above.
4. Your code style and formatting is OK as per the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide for Python.

The way you do it - you are reimplementing division and remainder from scratch with a loop. This is, well, useless.

The way you're doing it right now is OK if you can't use the above (course restrictions?), which would have helped a lot in this case - you could have used it to get rid of the `while` loop altogether, just looping over the allowed prices.

What can be done for your code is moving out the part which reimplements division and remainder into functions and using them, but then there remains no difference between the way I do it and the way I suggest for you to do it here.

(Note that the extraction into functions is necessary for reducing code duplication and extending your code to support more prices).

Here is my take:

```
def stamps(targetValue, prices):
    currentValue = targetValue
    sortedPrices = list(reversed(sorted(prices)))
    stampCounts = []
    for price in sortedPrices:
        stampCounts.append(currentValue // price) # note floor division
        currentValue = currentValue % price # remainder
    return dict(zip(sortedPrices, stampCounts)) # return a dict for caller's convenience
```

Comment: Thanks Tamoghna, I do have a loose understanding of division and remainder in modulus, but it hasn't come up in the course I'm currently at, so trying to figure out what the course designers are expecting me to do...

Comment: Much appreciate your input and tuition on this, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Using [builtin `divmod()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod):

```
def stamps(pence):
    fives, pence = divmod(pence, 5)
    twos, ones = divmod(pence, 2)
    return fives, twos, ones
```

Example:

```
>>> stamps(11)
(2, 0, 1)
```

that is you can get `11` pence using *two* 5p  and *one* 1p stamps.

Comment: Divmod is a new one for me - will have to learn to use it! Thanks for responding.

Comment: `divmod` is just a function for returning the quotient and remainder from an integer  division at the same time. Using existing APIs to shorten line count is cool, though.

Comment: @user133214 see above comment - it is just accomplishing the same thing as an explicit remainder calculation in half the line count.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury it is not about the line count.  It is about using the right tool for the job. Readability counts. It is a builtin function (it means that it is important enough to be always available). For integers: `divmod(a, b) == (a//b, a%b)`. Follow the link in the answer for more details.

Comment: However it gets justified, the side-effect of lower line-count is still appreciable. And forgive me if I disagree with you, but I consider readability (forgiving line count) to be equal in either the function or explicit approach.

Comment: You still have my +1, though.